# Attach 2 wooden broomsticks to make one long broomstick

Tags: wood, connectors

I have a branch cutter with a hollow handle. Something like this (except a little more simple):

[image]

Now buying long poles to suit the cutter were quite expensive so instead I drilled a hole in a regular wooden broomstick and inserted it into the handle of the cutter then fastened the stick inside with nut/bolt.

Problem is: the stick isn't quite long enough!

Is there any viable way to attach both sticks together (one on top of the other) to increase the length of the stick in a way that it will be strong enough to use to prune date palm branches?

Comment: excuse me if this isn't the best place to post this question. If it isn't - is there a more appropriate site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get long and/or extending poles usually sold for painting, but the standard screw on the end works for mops and brooms and accessories sold for such poles.  Some broom handles have the same screw socket in the end so they can be combined easily.

I have one made of fiberglass that extends to 20 feet. I used it for painting, and then for picking fruit, drying pasta, and any number of things.

Comment: could you include a link to demonstrate what this screw socket looks like, because I don't think that I have seen one in my area.

Comment: See http://www.homedepot.com/p/Mr-Longarm-Pro-Lok-23-ft-Adjustable-3-Section-Extension-Pole-2324/100177392  the screw is clearly visible on the top. A handle will have the negative of that in the hand-end.